# Cassandra and Hector = MultiGetSliceQuery, with Column-Values of various different types?

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

Hallo,

I do not understand, how to query cassandra with hector, but the column-values returned are not of one single type, but of many:

I put in ???? where I do not know what to do:

```
MultigetSliceQuery<String, String, ??????> multigetSliceQuery = HFactory.createMultigetSliceQuery(keyspace, stringSerializer, stringSerializer, ???????);
```

For for example, if all my column-values are of String type, I would put in String. But I have differnt ones like String, Integer, and byte[] in one single row. So I must pass in more then one Serializer.

How to solve this?

Thank you.

(can one pls create hector as tag? I am not allowed to do this)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the ByteBufferSerializer, and then convert the ByteBuffers returned from ByteBufferSerializer as the argument to StringSerializer and IntegerSerializer to convert the columns which are Strings and Integers.

Comment: That's right, that how you do this. This was a common question among hector users, but the best solution seems to be exactly what you suggest.

Comment: But this assumes you know the types of each column so as to be able to choose the correct (de) serializer in your code. What if you wanted to  deserialize an arbitrarily typed row? 

This is not as uncommon a use case as it may first appear. We needed to store arbitrary JSON objects in Cassandra, with each property in its own column. In the end we chose to reserve the first byte of the   column value to represent the type.

Although this solution works very well for us, and removes an insane amount of Hector boiler plate, most Hector-Cassandra experts don't recommend this approach.

Answer (score 6):

We provide arbitrary typing via a template-method pattern. See the test case:
https://github.com/rantav/hector/blob/master/core/src/test/java/me/prettyprint/cassandra/service/template/ColumnFamilyTemplateTest.java

The new getting started guide should be helpful as well:
https://github.com/rantav/hector/wiki/Getting-started-%285-minutes%29